# What happens when you alter a table column's length, but that length is already that length?

Tags: oracle, alter-table

Say we run an alter table command to change the table column length from 5 to 6. If we run the same command again, does Oracle alter the table again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does because database doesn't check the previous value it only sets the new value. The following demonstrates it.

```
SQL> conn jay
Connected.
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=true;

Session altered.

SQL> alter table test modify name varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test modify name varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> alter session set sql_trace=false;

Session altered.

SQL> exit
```

The following is formatted output of trace file generated by `tkprof`.

```
update tab$ set ts#=:2,file#=:3,block#=:4,bobj#=decode(:5,0,null,:5),tab#=
  decode(:6,0,null,:6),intcols=:7,kernelcols=:8,clucols=decode(:9,0,null,:9),
  audit$=:10,flags=:11,pctfree$=:12,pctused$=:13,initrans=:14,maxtrans=:15,
  rowcnt=:16,blkcnt=:17,empcnt=:18,avgspc=:19,chncnt=:20,avgrln=:21,
  analyzetime=:22,samplesize=:23,cols=:24,property=:25,degree=decode(:26,1,
  null,:26),instances=decode(:27,1,null,:27),dataobj#=:28,avgspc_flb=:29,
  flbcnt=:30,trigflag=:31,spare1=:32,spare2=decode(:33,0,null,:33),spare4=:34,
  spare6=:35 
where
 obj#=:1


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          6          4           2
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      0.00       0.00          0          6          4           2

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: CHOOSE
Parsing user id: SYS   (recursive depth: 1)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         0          0          0  UPDATE  TAB$ (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=175 us)
         1          1          1   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER TAB$ (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=11 us cost=2 size=142 card=1)
         1          1          1    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN I_OBJ# (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=5 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 3)

********************************************************************************

SQL ID: 6vqvn8ya0xybh Plan Hash: 829209562

update col$ set intcol#=:3,segcol#=:4,type#=:5,length=:6,precision#=decode(:5,
  182/*DTYIYM*/,:7,183/*DTYIDS*/,:7,decode(:7,0,null,:7)),scale=decode(:5,2,
  decode(:8,-127/*MAXSB1MINAL*/,null,:8),178,:8,179,:8,180,:8,181,:8,182,:8,
  183,:8,231,:8,null),null$=:9,fixedstorage=:10,segcollength=:11,col#=:12,
  property=:13,charsetid=:14,charsetform=:15,spare1=:16,spare2=:17,spare3=:18,
  deflength=decode(:19,0,null,:19),default$=:20 
where
 obj#=:1 and name=:2


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          6          4           2
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      0.00       0.00          0          6          4           2

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: CHOOSE
Parsing user id: SYS   (recursive depth: 1)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         0          0          0  UPDATE  COL$ (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=74 us)
         1          1          1   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER COL$ (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=19 us cost=2 size=61 card=1)
         1          1          1    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN I_OBJ# (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=6 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 3)

********************************************************************************

SQL ID: 4yyb4104skrwj Plan Hash: 2683643009

update obj$ set obj#=:4, type#=:5,ctime=:6,mtime=:7,stime=:8,status=:9,
  dataobj#=:10,flags=:11,oid$=:12,spare1=:13, spare2=:14 
where
 owner#=:1 and name=:2 and namespace=:3 and remoteowner is null and linkname 
  is null and subname is null


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          6          2           2
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      0.00       0.00          0          6          2           2

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: CHOOSE
Parsing user id: SYS   (recursive depth: 1)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         0          0          0  UPDATE  OBJ$ (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=114 us)
         1          1          1   INDEX RANGE SCAN I_OBJ2 (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=39 us cost=3 size=87 card=1)(object id 37)

********************************************************************************
```

As you can see the `tab$`, `col$`and `obj$` base tables are updated two times(evidenced by number of executes which is 2). These base tables stores the objects meta data.

Comment: So, the second alter table does alter the column again, but it seems like the execution time is much less? This more apparent if you are working on a table with more rows?

Comment: @Sun : Yeah, since the query has been parsed already Oracle just executes the query, it saves time and resources. Also the required data can be found in the buffer cache.